# Class Based Generic Views and DRY

Tags: django, django-views

I'm implementing class based views in Django 1.3 and I find myself in this scenario where my CreateView, UpdateView and DeleteView are almost identical. Is there a way to implement this with only a single view CreateUpdateView or something like that or is this the standard way to implement CBGV's?

Also, in ThingyAdd I haven't specified the model like I have in ThingyEdit, yet they both function fine. I'm making the assumption that the model is implied/picked-up by the model defined in the meta portion of the form_class, ThingyForm, which is a ModelForm. Is this assumption correct?

```
class ThingyAdd(AuthMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = ThingyForm
    context_object_name='object'
    template_name='change_form.html'
    success_url='/done/'

class ThingyEdit(AuthMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Thingy
    form_class = ThingyForm
    context_object_name='object'
    template_name='change_form.html'
    success_url='/done/'

class ThingyDelete(AuthMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Thingy
    form_class = ThingyForm
    context_object_name='object'
    template_name='delete_confirmation.html'
    success_url='/done/'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create another mixin

```
class ThingyMixin(object):
  model=Thingy
  form_class=ThingyForm
  template_name='change_form.html'
  context_object_name='object'
  success_url='/done/'
```

Then in your views:

```
class ThingyAdd( AuthMixin, ThingyMixin, CreateView ):
  pass

class ThingyEdit( AuthMixin, ThingyMixin, UpdateView ):
  pass

class ThingyDelete( AuthMixin, ThingyMixin, DeleteView ):
  template_name='delete_confirmation.html'
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Do I even need to specify the model attribute or is it implied by the model on the form_class?

Comment: You should only need to supply a model attribute on the DeleteView.